# Why the compiler flags “-mcpu=cortex-m3” goes wrong with stm32f10x?

Tags: gcc, makefile, arm, stm32, cortex-m

core of stm32f10x should be cortex-m3,with the flag"-mcpu=cortex-m3" ↓(this is section of makefile ):

```
CFLAGS += -T$(STD_PERIPH_LIBS)/Project/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Template/TrueSTUDIO/STM3210B-EVAL/stm32_flash.ld
CFLAGS += -mlittle-endian -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb-interwork
CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
```

the error :

```
/root/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: error: /tmp/ccwnNCUm.o uses VFP register arguments, t1.elf does not
/root/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /tmp/ccwnNCUm.o
/root/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: error: /tmp/ccaQhPT1.o uses VFP register arguments, t1.elf does not
/root/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /tmp/ccaQhPT1.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:39: recipe for target 't1.elf' failed
make: *** [t1.elf] Error 1
```

but after replacing "-mcpu=cortex-m3" with "-mcpu=cortex-m4",the error disappears and the program runs normally.

this introduction of "st.com"

> STM32F103 devices use the Cortex-M3 core, with a maximum CPU speed of
>   72 MHz.

so why is it "-mcpu=cortex-m4" instead of "-mcpu=cortex-m3"?
my arm-none-eabi-gcc:

> gcc version 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision
>   277599] (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major)

Comment: There isn't enough information here for a definitive answer -- we need a [mre].  However, the error messages suggest that details of the target platform are being specified inconsistently for your various build targets.

Comment: you have also these flags `-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16` and this is available only on Cortex-M4, so remove these two and it will probably work

Comment: The error `uses VFP register arguments` looks relatively clear to me. Why didn't you investigate what is a VFP (if you don't know) and presence or absence of FPU ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cortex-m3 doesn't have FPU option